# Spring-boot & multiple database connections: autowire service does not work

Tags: database, spring-boot, connection, vaadin8

I'm writing an Spring-boot application that needs to connect to at least 2 databases. 
    I have 1 project per database in order to define their domains, 1 project per database in order to define their services and 1 Vaadin project for the UI.

```
 - a business domain entity sample
    @Entity
    @Table(name="T_PARAMETER")
    public class Parameter extends BaseIdEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="par_cls")
    @NotNull
    private String parameterClass;

    @Column(name="par_cd")
    @NotNull
    private String parameterCode;

    @Column(name="par_lan")
    @NotNull
    private String language;

    @Column(name="par_sht_val")
    @NotNull
    private String parameterValueShort;

    @Column(name="par_lng_val")
    @NotNull
    private String parameterValueLong;

 - a authentication domain entity sample

    @Entity
    @Table(name="t_user", schema="authenticate")
    public class User extends BaseIdEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_cd")
    private String userCode;

    @Column(name="pwd")
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Column(name="new_pwd_req")
    @NotNull
    private boolean passwordRequired;

    @Column(name="acc_lck")
    @NotNull
    private boolean accountLocked;

There are repositories onto these 2 entities beans, they just extends the JpaRepository as hereunder:

public interface ParameterRepository extends JpaRepository<Parameter,Integer>{}
```

- the services are defined as hereunder:

  ```
  @Service
  @Transactional(transactionManager="authenticateTransactionManager")
  public class ServiceParameterImpl implements ServiceParameter {

  private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceParameterImpl.class);

  @Autowired
  private ParameterRepository parameterRepository;

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly=true,transactionManager="authenticateTransactionManager")
  public List<Parameter> findParameterHeader(String filter) {
  ```

  .../...
- The client application as:

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  @Configuration
  @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
      , HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
      , DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
  @ComponentScan(
      basePackages= {
              "org.associative.ui"
              ,"org.associative.service"
              })
  @Import({AssociativityConfiguration.class, AuthenticateConfiguration.class})
  public class Application {

  private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
  ```

  }
- and configurations:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  @EntityScan(basePackages= "org.associative.domain.associativity")
  @EnableJpaRepositories(
      basePackages = "org.associative.domain.associativity.repository"
      , entityManagerFactoryRef = "associativityEntityManager"
      , transactionManagerRef = "associativityTransactionManager"
      )
      @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db.associativity")
      public class AssociativityConfiguration {

  private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AssociativityConfiguration.class);

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  private final static String ASSOCIATIVITY_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "db.associativity.classname";
  private final static String ASSOCIATIVITY_URL = "db.associativity.connectionUrl";
  private final static String ASSOCIATIVITY_USERNAME = "db.associativity.username";
  private final static String ASSOCIATIVITY_PASSWORD = "db.associativity.password";

  private final static String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";

  @Bean(name = "associativityDataSource")
  public DataSource datasource() {
      DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
              .driverClassName(env.getProperty(ASSOCIATIVITY_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME))
              .url(env.getProperty(ASSOCIATIVITY_URL))
              .username(env.getProperty(ASSOCIATIVITY_USERNAME))
              .password(env.getProperty(ASSOCIATIVITY_PASSWORD)).build();

      if (log.isTraceEnabled())
          log.trace(String.format("associativityConfiguration datasource:%s", dataSource.toString()));

      return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean(name = "associativityEntityManager")
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "associativity")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
          EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
          @Qualifier("associativityDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

      Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
      jpaProperties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));

      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder.dataSource(dataSource)
              .packages("org.associative.domain.authenticate").persistenceUnit("pu_associativity").properties(jpaProperties)
              .build();
      em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter); // not mandatory definition

      return em;
  }

  @Bean(name = "associativityTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager associativityTransactionManager(
          @Qualifier("associativityEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
      return transactionManager;
  }
  ```

  }
- and

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  @EntityScan(basePackages= "org.associative.domain.authenticate")
  @EnableJpaRepositories(
      basePackages = "org.associative.domain.authenticate.repository"
      , entityManagerFactoryRef = "authenticateEntityManager"
      , transactionManagerRef = "authenticateTransactionManager"
      )
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="db.authenticate")
  public class AuthenticateConfiguration {

  private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticateConfiguration.class);

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  private final static String AUTHENTICATE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME= "db.authenticate.classname";
  private final static String AUTHENTICATE_URL = "db.authenticate.connectionUrl";
  private final static String AUTHENTICATE_USERNAME = "db.authenticate.username";
  private final static String AUTHENTICATE_PASSWORD = "db.authenticate.password";
  private final static String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "authenticateDataSource")
  public DataSource datasource() {
      DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
              .driverClassName(env.getProperty(AUTHENTICATE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME))
              .url(env.getProperty(AUTHENTICATE_URL))
              .username(env.getProperty(AUTHENTICATE_USERNAME))
              .password(env.getProperty(AUTHENTICATE_PASSWORD))
              .build();

      if ( log.isTraceEnabled()) log.trace(String.format("authenticateDataSource datasource:%s", dataSource.toString()));

      return dataSource;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name="authenticateEntityManager")
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "authenticate")
  //https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/tag/enablejparepositories/
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory( 
          EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("authenticateDataSource")DataSource dataSource) {

      Map<String,Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
      jpaProperties.put(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));

      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder
              .dataSource(dataSource)
              .packages("org.associative.domain.authenticate")
              .persistenceUnit("pu_authenticate")
              .properties(jpaProperties)
              .build();
      em.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);

      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter); // not mandatory definition

      return em;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name="authenticateTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager authenticateTransactionManager(
          @Qualifier("authenticateEntityManager")EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
      return transactionManager;
  }
  ```

  }

  I'm facing an issue when a service is built by using autowiring in the construction of my client interface:

  @SpringUI
      public class ParameterListView extends CssLayout implements Serializable {

  ```
  private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ParameterListView.class);

  @Autowired
  private ParameterController controller;

  @PostConstruct
  private void initView() {
      if ( log.isTraceEnabled() ) log.trace(String.format("initView:%s", "no param"));

      Grid<Parameter> grid = new Grid<>();
      this.addComponent(grid);

      grid.setItems(controller.getParameterHeader(""));

      grid.addColumn(Parameter::getParameterClass);
      grid.addColumn(Parameter::getParameterValueShort);
      grid.addColumn(Parameter::getParameterValueLong);
  ```

> ```
> 2017-12-01 14:20:07.151 ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication Application startup failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parameterControllerImpl': Unsatisfied
> ```
>
> dependency expressed through field 'serviceParameter'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'serviceParameterImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'parameterRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'parameterRepository': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class
>   org.associative.domain.associativity.Parameter

I already spent a lot of time in order to solve the multiple database connections because I was thinking this issue comes from a definition problem but I'm not sure now.
    So, what should I look to in order to solve this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Holy. Please take a look at [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read them carefully. Especially the part about _"Minimal"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your stack trace is a clue: `Not a managed type: class org.associative.domain.associativity.Parameter`. Hibernate doesn't know about your Parameter entity.

In the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` you set packages to scan to `org.associative.domain.authenticate`. Your Parameter entity is not under this package.

This should fix the problem:

```
.packages("org.associative.domain.authenticate", "org.associative.domain.associativity")
```